# Installing Anaconda on top of other versions of software

Tags: software-installation, anaconda, spyder, scikit-learn

I put a decent amount of work into installing a suite of data science related applications such as ipython, spyder, numpy and scikit-learn using apt-get and pip.  Then I was directed to Anaconda which offers a bash script to install them all.

Question: If install Anaconda (https://www.continuum.io/downloads) on top of the things I already installed am I likely to run into conflicts?  Should I put in the work to uninstall existing versions first? (I'm not eager to do this, because if I run into issues with Anaconda I'll have to do it all over again.)

Any advice much appreciated!